# Redirecting in React with CRSF and custom headers

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest, csrf, multipartform-data

I'm trying to

1. From React/S3 - Retrieve CSRF from body of extenal site (EC2)
2. Submit form data (email/password) along with the retrieved CRSF and a custom header specifying the database
3. Redirect the users browser.

The CSRF pulls in with

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var csrfToken = this.responseXML.getElementsByName('csrf_token')[0].getAttribute('value');
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "url");
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.send();
```

and the page redirects with

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
      
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        
        if(req.status == 200)
         
          document.write(req.responseText);
        else
          alert("Error loading page\n");
      }
    };
    
    req.setRequestHeader("X-Odoo-dbfilter", 'data'); 
    req.setRequestHeader("x-crsf-token", csrfToken);
    req.send();
```

and I've been able to submit a plain-html form with the following;

```
const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = method;
    form.action = path;

    for (const key in params) {
      if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
        hiddenField.name = key;
        hiddenField.value = params[key];

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
```

But combining this logic has been problematic. I'm struggling to find a method that allows me to submit form data, a custom header, and redirect the user. In my latest attempt I've tried to use fetch

```
fetch('url', {
  method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
  mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
  cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
  credentials: "include", // include, *same-origin, omit
  headers: {
      //"Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "X-Odoo-dbfilter": "data"

  },
  redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
  referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
  body: formData, // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
})
.then(response => {
    
    if (response.redirected) {
        window.location.href = response.url;
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.info('here be errors');
});
```

But still bit unclear about what approach is best.

Comment: Where do you store your session? Cookies or localStorage?

Comment: localStorage @diogo.silva